# Java MVC button not calling function

Tags: java, model-view-controller, jbutton

I'm still a beginner at Java and this is my first time trying to use the MVC-model. So far everything worked and I've done two small examples successfuly.

However now I'm having an issue in my current project where a button-click is supposed to start a search in a database. I've already tested it all and calling the method to search the database in my main class works, but trying to let the button call said funtion doesn't return me any result or error.

My View:

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class View extends JFrame{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public static final String SEARCH = "SEARCH";

private JButton searchbutton = new JButton();

public View() {
    this.setTitle("Betriebsnummersuche TBBBST");

    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    this.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    searchbutton.setText("Search");
    searchbutton.setActionCommand(View.SEARCH);
    this.add(searchbutton);

    this.setSize(600, 400);
    setResizable(false);
    //this.pack();
}

public JButton getButton() {
    return searchbutton;
}

}
```

My Model:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.Observable;
import default.dbconnect.dao.impl.ResultsDaoImpl;

public class Model extends Observable{

public void search() throws SQLException, IOException {
    ResultsDaoImpl result1 = new ResultDaoImpl();
    result1.getResults();
}
}
```

My Controller:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.Observable;
import java.util.Observer;

public class Controller implements Observer, ActionListener{

private Model model;
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
private View view;

public Controller(Model model, View view) {
    this.model = model;
    this.view = view;

    model.addObserver(this);

    view.getButton().addActionListener(this);

    view.setVisible(true);
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    switch (e.getActionCommand()) {
    case View.SEARCH:
        try {
            model.search();
        } catch (SQLException e1) {
            System.out.println("A SQL-error occured: ");
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            System.out.println("An error occured: ");
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        break;

    default:
        System.out.println("Search error: " + e.getActionCommand());
        break;
    }

}

@Override
public void update(Observable o, Object arg) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

}
```

And last my Main:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import default.mvc.Controller;
import default.mvc.Model;
import default.mvc.View;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException, IOException {

    Model model = new Model();
    View view = new View();
    Controller controller = new Controller(model, view);
}

}
```

Can anybody tell me what I'm doing wrong here? Like I said, the search itself worked, so I'm assuming my mistake has something to do with my Actionlistener for my B

EDIT: Code for my ResultsDaoImpl class:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import de.drv.dsrv.betriebsnumemrsuchetbbbst.dao.ResultsDao;
import de.drv.dsrv.betriebsnummersuchetbbbst.business.ResultsBean;

public class ResultsDaoImpl extends AbstractDao implements ResultsDao {
//Only show first 10 results, change later!!!
private static final String AllResults = "SELECT BBSTBBNR, BBSTPLZ, BBSTNABEG FROM BP.TBBBST FETCH FIRST 10 ROWS ONLY";

public Collection<ResultsBean> getResults() throws SQLException,
        IOException {
    final Collection<ResultsBean> endresult = new ArrayList<ResultsBean>();

    ResultSet resultset = null;
    try {
        resultset = getResultset(AllResults);

        // while loop for showing all data
        while (resultset.next()) {
            ResultsBean results = new ResultsBean();
            int resultid = resultset.getInt(1);
            String resultplz = resultset.getString(2);
            String resultname = resultset.getString(3);
            ergebnis.add(results);
            System.out.println("Results: " + resultid + " " + resultplz + " " + resultname);
        }

    } catch (SQLException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("An error occurred processing SQL statement (getResults)");
    } catch (NullPointerException npe) {
        System.out.println("NullPointerException");
    } finally {

        closeConnection(resultset);

    }

    return endresult;
}
```

}

Comment: Try to put a println before the switch in Controller.actionPerformed to make sure it really passes there.

Comment: Apparently it does not pass there. Already tried that before (forgot to mention) and again just now. So it apparently doesn't call the actionPerformed function.

Comment: You should probably add that println to the code in the question to show you've tried it, along with a comment stating it doesn't get called.

Comment: Incidentally, I have just copied and compiled your code and it works fine for me (I changed the `Model.search()` method to just `System.out.println("search!");` and it does indeed get called).  So all the code you've posted is fine.  Try stepping through the code with a debugger to see what happens.  Or add _loads_ of `System.out.println` calls all over the place to see where it appears to stop.

Answer (score 1):

Something is wrong with this part:

ResultsDaoImpl result1 = new ResultDaoImpl();

Please provide code for it. Calling stack is ok.

Comment: Yes. When you are trying to find errors first write some simple code into search() method.

Comment: I edited the question and added my ResultsDaoImpl class.

Comment: Add some System.out.println() after this
resultset = getResultset(AllResults);
If it shows it means that your ResultSet is retreival is not good.